# Branching issue for developing new feature (dependent on other projects)

Tags: svn

Imagine you have a few projects in SVN:

```
SVN
 |-- Project_A
     |-- trunk
     |-- branches
     |-- tags
 |-- Project_B
 |-- Project_C
 |-- Project_D
```

All projects also have trunk, branches, tags structure as in Project_A.
`Project_B` is used in `Project_A` (for example, .dll used in .exe).

Now, I want to add a feature to `Project_A`, so I create a new branch under `Project_A\branches\Feature_A`. While developing `Feature_A`, I face a situation where
 I need to do some changes also in `Project_B` (add\change code that will be used by `Feature_A`).

So, logically, I create new branch `Project_B\branches\Code_changes_for_feature_A`.
When I'm finished -- merging `Code_changes_for_feature_A` to `Project_B\trunk` is done and I can return back to developing `Feature_A`. 
So far so good...

But what to do if `Feature_A` requiers changes not only in `Project_B` but also in other projects (`Project_C`, `Project_D` and others)? Should I, each time, create new
branches in each project that will be changed? I's a bit overhead, as for me.

Is there a possibility to create branch that will aggregate (contain all files) `Project_A` and `Project_B` for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I, each time, create new branches in each project that will be changed?

You *have* to do it. But, from other side you can try to use "lazy way" (SVN externals and SVN 1.8.* are not mandatory, but preferred):

- Create in each dependent (B|C|D|...) repository permanent WIP-branch
- Link this branch's PEG-revision from Project_A feature branch
- Merge dependent finished changes into corresponding trunks and change definition of externals into trunk also after merging Project_A's devel into trunk
- Keep WIPs in sync with changes (independent from WIP) in trunks of slave projects (sync merge)

Instead of "branch per change" you'll use "range per change" for the cost of harder restoring history of WIP's changes: you'll must to write good commit message all time